# Prove $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\sin{n\pi\sqrt{2}}}=-\frac{13\pi^3}{360\sqrt2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

I faced a problem with one very interesting series:
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^3\sin{\pi\sqrt{2}n}}$
I know that the answer is $-\frac{13\pi^3}{360\sqrt{2}}$, but I couldn’t get it.

At first I have tried the fraction decomposition of the function $\frac{1}{\sin{\pi\sqrt{2}n}}$, but when I’ve done this I faced a new series that I can’t handle $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{n^2(2n^2-k^2)}$

Next try was to just apply the residue theorem to first or second series, but I didn’t get anything good.

At last I’ve tried to find some function whose residues will be members of the series(just like you can do with this series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\sinh{\pi n})^2}$)

So, any ideas or approaches will be appreciated!
Especially some tricky methods, because I believe that this value can be obtained without “deep math”.

Comment: Warning: for $n=0$ your first addend ruins the problem. You have to edit.

Comment: Thanks, I didn’t notice this.

Comment: Actually the sum  is $-\frac{13 \pi ^3}{360 \sqrt{2}}$

Comment: See [Ron Gordon's website](http://residuetheorem.com/2016/02/17/a-sum-i-can-only-imagine-being-evaluated-using-the-residue-theorem/).

Comment: Ha-ha, now I see that I’m blind. I was so close to the solution with function $\frac{1}{z^3\sin{\pi z}\sin{sqrt(2) \pi z}}$, but stacked at term $(-1)^n$ at residues. Anyway, very thanks, it was a cool solution.