# Evaluating $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{n^2\left(k^2-2n^2 \right)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

I am trying to evaluate the following series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3\sin\left(\sqrt{2}\pi n \right)}\tag{a} $$
where, using the well-known result:
$$\frac{1}{\sin\left(\pi x\right)}=\frac{2x}{\pi}\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2-x^2}+\frac{1}{\pi x}\tag{1} $$
connecting $(1)$ in $(a)$ and $x\to \sqrt{2}n$ got the step:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^3\sin\left(\sqrt{2}\pi n \right)}=\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{\pi}\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{n^2\left(k^2-2n^2 \right)}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}\pi}\zeta(4)\tag{b} $$
I tried to apply partial fractions in the double series above, then i found that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{n^2\left(k^2-2n^2 \right)}=\frac54\zeta(4)+2\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{k^2\left(k^2-2n^2\right)}\tag{2} $$
To conclude, I do not know to what extent this last step can help to solve the Double Series. Maybe I'm not seeing the obvious. It will be interesting to see some approach to resolve it. At [Wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20%28sum%20%28-1%29%5E%28k-1%29%2F%5Bn%5E2%28k%5E2-2n%5E2%29%5D%20from%20k%3D1%20to%20infinity%29%20from%20n%3D1%20to%20infinity), she is:
$$\therefore\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k-1}}{n^2\left(k^2-2n^2 \right)}=-\frac{17}{16}\zeta(4).  $$

Comment: For your original problem, see [this link](http://residuetheorem.com/2016/02/17/a-sum-i-can-only-imagine-being-evaluated-using-the-residue-theorem/?cb=04592218141732487) (also mentioned [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3925348)).

Comment: @metamorphy Very good! Thank you for the informations. Too bad i don't understand much about contour integration :-/. I'm trying for real methods, which is more intuitive for me.

Comment: @metamorphy Cool that we arrived in the same double series. At Wolfram we have a closed form for her. But I'm not able to prove it, unfortunately.

Comment: You need to be super careful when exchanging the order of summation.  In cases like this, it can fail.