# Evaluate $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3\sin(\sqrt2n\pi)} $ without using Residue theorem

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, hyperbolic-functions

I've seen a few posts already discussed about this problem but i want to know is there another way to solve without using residue theorem ,because it may be a challenge for me if it's possible to solve
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^3\sin(\sqrt2n\pi)}.$$

Comment: Maybe link to the posts you've seen on this problem?

Comment: here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1658250/compute-the-series-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n3-sinn-pi-sqrt2
https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3925348/prove-sum-n-1-infty-frac1n3-sinn-pi-sqrt2-frac13-pi3360-sqr?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Riemann Seriously, do you think that’s a valuable edit?

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Yes, I think so !!

Comment: @Riemann Editing a question bumps it back to the front page.  Making small, relatively inconsequential edits to old questions doesn't really do much to help improve the overall quality of the site.  For something like this, which really doesn't meet the quality standards for the site, and which is a duplicate question, it is generally better to let it go.